# Restriciting enterting of alphabets in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am using a text box with type number. For xperia mobile's if i am using the same text box,it is showing a keyboard with all the value.So i am able to type any value. I want to restrict the user from entering any value.User have to enter only number.I tried the following code.

*

```
document.getElementById('loginPin').addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
     var keyCode = ('which' in e) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
     var isNumeric = (keyCode < 48  KeyboardEvent.DOM_VK_0  && keyCode > 57  KeyboardEvent.DOM_VK_9 ) ||
                 (keyCode < 96  KeyboardEvent.DOM_VK_NUMPAD0  && keyCode > 105  KeyboardEvent.DOM_VK_NUMPAD9 );
     var modifiers = (event.altKey || event.ctrlKey || event.shiftKey);

     return !isNumeric || modifiers;
    var V = $(this).val();
    alert("hai"+V);
    if (isNaN(V)) {
        $(this).val(V.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''));
    }


}, false);
```

*

It is working if the alert is there, else it is not working. So any suggestion to solve this.

Comment: Why would you do that on the client? To me this sounds like wasted time to target a device that accounts for approximately 0.2% of website traffic. And you need a server-side check anyway. So let users whose browsers support HTML5 form fields only input numbers. For older devices present an error message if there was an unexpected input by the user. And of course you should describe the format for your users in a little help text…

Comment: they dont want error message they want to block the text from entering.this is my requirement and any suggestion to solve it.

Comment: I would suggest using an existing plugin to validate your form. like http://jqueryvalidation.org/. That will make it easy to do any form of validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
function numericInput(inputId){

        $('#' + inputId).keyup(function (e) {
            var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]+$");

            if (!regex.test($(this).val())) {
                $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0, -1));
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }

        });
}
```